# google maps api autocomplete works at localhost but does not work on the server

Tags: google-maps

I used google maps api for autocomplete of places.

Everythings works in localhost, but when i publish and upload it on server, it doesn't work...Why it happen? the dropdown of places does not show.

Here is my HTML:

```
  <input type="text" id="autocomplete">
```

Here is my JS:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
  <script>
var autocomplete;

function initialize() {

  autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
    (document.getElementById('autocomplete')), {
      types: ['(cities)'],
      componentRestrictions: { country: "ph" }
    });
  google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function () {
    fillInAddress();
  });

}

placeParser = function(place){
  result = {};
  for(var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++){
    ac = place.address_components[i];
    result[ac.types[0]] = ac.long_name;
  }
  return result;
};


function fillInAddress() {

  var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
  document.getElementById("latitude").value = place.geometry.location.lat();
  document.getElementById("longitude").value = place.geometry.location.lng();

  components = placeParser(place);

}

initialize();
```

Answer (score 4):

There are 3 issues

1. you are calling `initialize` without knowing if the maps-API already has been loaded, remove the call of initialize and use the `callback`-parameter of the maps-API instead
2. the maps-API now **requires a key**.
   As it seems there are circumstances(undocumented) where it may work without a key(I guess for requests from localhost and from domains  which have been used the maps-API before a key has been required), probably your domain doesn't match this criteria, so you should/must [**use a key**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key)
3. (Additionally)I would call it a bug by google:
   As it seems, now the use of the Places-library requires that the **Places API Web Service** also has been activated for a project( before it was sufficient to activate only the **Maps JavaScript API** )

Comment: I have tried putting key with this I tested this with my two websites.  The first one pretty works and its fine when I use it on my second website it does not work.  I wonder why the code is the same and this does not show a map just like a dropdown of places.

Comment: did you enable the Places API Web Service? Did you add referers for both websites? Can you post the URLs?

Comment: sir this is the link of my first website which I place the google maps autocomplete http://filipinohomes.com/search/ ....and then this is the second website which I place the autocomplete http://leuteriorealty.com/search/.. the codes are the same... yesterday the autocomplete does not work on the second website when I tried it this morning it already works I don't know why.

Comment: And now I tried it again 30 minutes after ..it does not work...what is the problem of this sir?

Comment: both sites doesn't use a key. **A key is required now**, the Javascript-API doesn't work anymore without a key(except for implementations which have been created before June 22)

Comment: sir I already added an API key on this page http://filipinohomes.com/ yet when I check the console it appears that NoApiKey and it does not work now...yesterday this pretty works...sometimes it works sometimes not..what is this sir?

Comment: The key obviously isn't valid(there is also an  InvalidKey-error)....there is a leading `&` in the key, remove it

Comment: sir check this http://filipinohomes.com/search/test3.html i copied the code here straight from google...i did not modify anything...there is no error now in the JS i already put an API key....yet it does not show the dropdown...hoping you can help me sir...I know tomorrow this will work and sometimes not.

Comment: currently the autocomplete works for me, so I can't tell you what's the issue. I will test again later, maybe it doesn't work then.

Comment: Sir i already know what is happening...I put an API key then I check its usage. The key only limits up to 1,000 usage per day and the usage is very full and that is why the drop down will not work. Thank you for your guidance